# Why does my TreeView look like this?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

```
    <TreeView SelectedValuePath="{Binding Id}" ItemsSource="{Binding MySourceHere}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LocalCategories:BaseCategory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subcategories}">
                <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                </TreeViewItem>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

[image]

What is the correct way to mark-up a `TreeViewItem`, if not `<TreeViewItem Header="text" />`?

If I remove the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` it renders fine, but of course I lose the hierarchy.

[image]

**Edit**

Should have been

```
<TreeViewItem IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding DisplayName}" />
```

However, it still looks weird, why do I have a box within the item?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HierarchicalDataTemplate is not supposed to include a TreeViewItem. Try this:

```
<TreeView SelectedValuePath="{Binding Id}" ItemsSource="{Binding MySourceHere}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LocalCategories:BaseCategory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subcategories}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```